# Why are my social media icons/buttons wrapping?

Tags: css, button, icons, social-media

I am trying to align all of the social media icons on one line, but for some reason they are wrapping. (twitter and fbconnect):

http://bit.ly/IqwM20

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried a lot of stuff (floating left, increasing the containing div container's size, using display: inline-block ) but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks,
gvanto

Comment: whats the green bar on there for?

Comment: green bar was just to view the container (I guess it should have given me a clue it was too small!). Btw does anyone know which fb count button just has a simple count next to it? I selected that I thought would do this on the fb dev like button page but it dont look right to me ... its an iframe version

Comment: use http://www.floatingsocialmediabuttons.com/

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the file **pme.css** as follows:

**Line 140**

```
#socmedia-bar {
clear: both;
float: right;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
height: 21px;
background-color: #6F6;
width: 345px;
}
```

**Line 150**

```
#socmedia-bar .region-socmed-icons {
float: left;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
position: relative;
}
```

**Line 178**

```
#socmedia-bar .region.region-facebook-connect {
float: right;
height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much you are my hero! I was on this for hours. Admittedly not a css expert :-D Thx again

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be lack of horizontal space so the twitter button wraps.

If you specify a `width` on `#socmedia-bar .region-socmed-icons` of say `250px` they will all sit on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the social media buttons on the top section, then you have the widths wrong. The social media buttons total width comes to `250px` but the wrapper div is only `200px` wide. Hence the wrapping. Increase the width of the wrapper `#socmedia-bar` and it will be fine.